# How restore to previous committed version in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs

My company is using cvs to manage project.
I commit project when a module has been completed. But find a problem, it only has `restore to Lastest from Head` in `replace with` menu. So how should i do if i want to replace to specific  version i committed?

ps:I only use commit to upload my project, haven't give a tag name or version.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is shared with CVS, there should be a `Replace with>HEAD` and `Replace with>Another branch or version`.  The second one should do what you want.

The other option is to look at the file in the History view.  You can right click on a specific version and either get the contents, or `Get Sticky Revision` which will set the version of that file (ex: 1.3).  You have to remember to unstick it, though, or updating to HEAD will still leave that file at that specific version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.`Replace with>Another branch or version`, this can actually solve this problem. But the second method you provide seems can only be used when just one file need to restore, what i want now is to replace the hole project. Because when i commit a project, i must input some comment, So i think there may be only one way to restore project to certain timeline.